# Drupal user permissions & odd content types

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7

I have a permissions problem in Drupal. I want users to be able to create a certain node type, but there are two different paths I need to give them permissions for to let them do this. The type is content created by a module called isbn2node, and there are two ways to make content through it, each with different paths:

```
?=node/add/isbn2node-book

?=node/add/isbn2node_book/isbn2node
```

One has an underscore and the other one has a hyphen. The first path leads to a form that lets users enter information on a book manually; the second path lets them enter an ISBN, searches for it, and populates the form for them based on the results.

I've changed permissions in the People menu so they can add isbn2node-book content manually using the first path, but there isn't an option to let them use the second method. Aliasing the url so it didn't have `node/add` in the path didn't work either.

Creating a duplicate content type seems like an ugly solution to this; is there a more elegant way to let users access that second path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little code in a custom module using [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) should do it.

$node is either a node object or the machine name of the content type on which to perform the access check (if the node is being created then the $node object is not available so it will be a string instead).

So this should do it:

```
function MY_MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
    if ($op == 'create') {
        $type = $node;
        if($type == 'book' && $account->uid) return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
}
```

Comment: The $account->uid bit just confirms that the user if logged in

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like a nice & neat solution. A first quick attempt to implement this got me the error:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

... But I'm pretty sure that's my bad; I'll troubleshoot when I get home and report back.

Comment: I've updated my answer - $node is not an object when $op is create.

Comment: I figured it out! Your code works for all the other content types on my site, but it turns out this specific module was set up so users need the "Administer Nodes" permission to run the custom search the second path sends them to. I've linked to a fix below. 

Thanks - I learnt about hooks & PHP getting this sorted this out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, and the issues I was having were specific to this content type. The ISBN2Node module requires users to have the Administer Nodes permission to use its lookup and bulk import features.

There is some extra code for the module's hook_permission and hook_menu sections submitted as a fix in the module's [issues thread](https://drupal.org/comment/5506694#comment-5506694).

Comment: Reading that thread I would say a better solution may be to use hook_menu_alter in your own module as opposed to making changes to the isbn module. That way if an update for the isbn modules comes your changes wont' be lost.